# Jooq is unable to find driver for postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, jooq

I have a spring-boot app that uses gradle, postgres and jooq. 
I want Jooq's code generator to create the classes for me but during `gradle clean build` I get an error regarding to the driver

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver`

I don't understand why the driver is not found. This are some of the relevant aspects of my `gradle.build` file:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.2.RELEASE"
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.1'
}
```

I an using version `2.0.2.RELEASE` of spring boot. This are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$SPRING_VERSION"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$SPRING_VERSION"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq:$SPRING_VERSION"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$SPRING_VERSION"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq:$SPRING_VERSION"
 implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
```

}

This is the Jooq config i have in my gradle file

````
jooq {
   myApp(sourceSets.main) {
       jdbc {
           driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
           url = "jdbc:postgresql://${db_host}:${db_port}/${db_name}"
           user = "${db_username}"
           password = "${db_password}"
           schema = 'public'
       }
       generator {
           name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
           strategy {
               name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
           }
           database {
               name = 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
               inputSchema = 'public'
           }
           generate {
               relations = true
               deprecated = false
               records = true
               immutablePojos = false
               fluentSetters = true
           }
           target {
               packageName = 'com.mycompany.mayapp.model.jooq'
               directory = 'out/production/classes/generated'
           }
       }
   }
}```
````

Comment: You need to add the drivers to the `jooqRuntime` configuration. see https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum That did the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [gradle-jooq-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) needs dependencies in a separate configuration. It  uses the `jooqRuntime` configuration to detect the needed dependencies, it doesn't use the `compile` or `implementation` configuration.

Adding the following to your dependencies should do the trick

```
jooqRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
```

This way the plugin picks up the driver and will generate the model classes.

Comment: jooqRuntime is now jooqGenerator as of the gradle-jooq-plugin version 5.0.